# program crashes after executing the second case in a switch

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Programm that is supposed to combine a few different Programms I wrote before (all of then worked).
My Problem:
After case 'r' has been executed the Programm crashes.
My Programm(Sorry for the Text beeing in german but I guess that doesnt matter too much. If it does just tell me and I will change it to english.):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "GameMaster.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

string vBefehlH = "help";       //vergleichsBefehlX
string vBefehlR = "rdm";
string vBefehlI = "items";
string eBefehl;                 //eingegebener Befehl
char Befehl;

cout << "------Willkommen GameMaster------" << endl <<endl;
cout << "Geben sie *help* ein, um eine Liste der verf\201gbaren Befehle auszugeben." << endl;
while(1)
{
    cin >> Befehl;              //wartet auf die eingabe eines Befehls

    if(eBefehl == vBefehlH)
    {
        Befehl = 'h';
    }

    if(eBefehl == vBefehlR)
    {
        Befehl = 'r';
    }

    switch(Befehl)
    {
        case 'h':       //gibt die Hilfe aus
        {       
            cout << "help       -Gibt eine Liste aller verf\201gbaren Befehle im aktuellen Bereich aus." << endl;
            cout << "rdm        -Erstellt einen neuen Charakter." << endl;
            cout << "items      -Geht in den Item Bereich." << endl;

            break;
        }

        case 'r':
        {
            string Name;
            string Geschlecht;
            string Rasse;
            string Beruf;
            string Hautfarbe;
            string Haarfarbe;
            string Augenfarbe;

            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> Name;            //cin muss aus irgendeinem Grund doppelt sein. Sonst wird es übersprungen.
            cin >> Name;
            cout << "Geschlecht: ";
            cin >> Geschlecht;
            cout << "Rasse: ";
            cin >> Rasse;
            cout << "Beruf: ";
            cin >> Beruf;
            cout << "Hautfarbe: ";
            cin >> Hautfarbe;
            cout << "Haarfarbe: ";
            cin >> Haarfarbe;
            cout << "Augenfarbe: ";
            cin >> Augenfarbe;

            Charakter Charakter1(Name, Geschlecht, Rasse, Beruf, Hautfarbe, Haarfarbe, Augenfarbe);

            Charakter1.Werte();
            Charakter1.grWerte();
            Charakter1.spWerte();
            Charakter1.SchreibCharakter();
            cout << endl << "Der Charakter wurde erfolgreich erstellt und befindet sich in *rdmCharakter.txt*" << endl;
            system ("pause");
            break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Now I dont think there is something wrong with the other sorce files in my Project but I'll just put them in down here just in case.

GameMaster.h

```
#ifndef GameMasterH
#define GameMasterH

using namespace std;

class Charakter
{
private:                
                        //Die Grundinformationen, welche manuell eingegeben         
werden
string Name;
string Geschlecht;
string Rasse;
string Beruf;
string Hautfarbe;
string Haarfarbe;
string Augenfarbe;
                        //Die Werte, welche durch RNG bestimmt werden
int Wert[9];
int spWert[58];         //Spezialwerte
int grWert[3];          //Alter/Größe/Gewicht


public:

//Konstruktor
Charakter(string, string, string, string, string, string, string);
//Destruktor
~Charakter();
//mothoden
void Werte();               //bestimmt die Grundwerte
void SchreibCharakter();    //Schreibt den Charakter
void spWerte();             //bestimmt die Spezialwerte
void grWerte();             //bestimmt Alter/Größe/Gewicht
};
```

Charakter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "GameMaster.h"

using namespace std;

//Konstruktor: Weist Die Grundinfos zu.
Charakter::Charakter(string N, string G, string R, string B, string HAU,     string HAA, string A) 
{
Name = N;
Geschlecht = G;
Rasse = R;
Beruf = B;
Hautfarbe = HAU;
Haarfarbe = HAA;
Augenfarbe = A;
}

//Destruktor
Charakter::~Charakter()
{

}

void Charakter::Werte()                     //Weist die Grundwerte zu
{
srand(time(0));

for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    Wert[i] = 8+(rand()%7);
}
}

void Charakter::grWerte()                   //Weist Alter, Größe und Gewicht zu
{
srand(time(0));

grWert[1] = 18+(rand()%43);
grWert[2] = 160+(rand()%41);
grWert[3] = 70+(rand()%41); 
}

void Charakter::spWerte()                   //Weist Die spezifischen Werte zu
{
srand(time(0));

for(int i = 1; i < 58; i++)
{
    spWert[i] = (rand()%6);
}
}

void Charakter::SchreibCharakter()          //Schreibt die Textdatei
{
FILE* CharakterFile;

CharakterFile = fopen("rdmCharakter.txt", "w");

if(CharakterFile != NULL)
{
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Name: %s \n", Name.c_str());
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Geschlecht: %s \n", Geschlecht.c_str());
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Rasse: %s \n", Rasse.c_str());  
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Beruf: %s \n", Beruf.c_str());  
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Alter: %d \n", grWert[1]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Hautfarbe: %s \n", Hautfarbe.c_str());
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Haarfarbe: %s \n", Haarfarbe.c_str());
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Augenfarbe: %s \n", Augenfarbe.c_str());
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Größe: %d \n", grWert[2]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Gewicht: %d \n", grWert[3]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "Persönlichkeit: \n\n\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        Eigenschaften \n \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MU: %d \n", Wert[1]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KL: %d \n", Wert[2]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "IN: %d \n", Wert[3]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "CH: %d \n", Wert[4]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "FF: %d \n", Wert[5]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "GE: %d \n", Wert[6]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KO: %d \n", Wert[7]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KK: %d \n\n\n", Wert[8]);

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "VORTEILE:           NACHTEILE:\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        HANDWERKSTALENTE\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ALCHEMIE        (KL/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[1]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HANDEL          (KL/IN/CH): %d \n", spWert[2]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HEILKUNDE-GIFT      (MU/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[3]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HEILKUNDE-KRANK     (MU/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[4]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HEILKUNDE-SEELE     (KL/IN/CH): %d \n", spWert[5]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HEILKUNDE-WUNDEN    (KL/FF/FF): %d \n", spWert[6]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HOLZBEARBEITUNG     (KL/KK/FF): %d \n", spWert[7]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "LEDERBEARBEITUNG    (KL/FF/FF): %d \n", spWert[8]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "METALLBEARBEITUNG   (KL/FF/KK): %d \n", spWert[9]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "STEINBEARBEITUNG    (FF/FF/KK): %d \n", spWert[10]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "STOFFBEARBEITUNG    (KL/FF/FF): %d \n", spWert[11]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KOCHEN&BACKEN       (KL/IN/FF): %d \n", spWert[12]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHLÖSSERKNACKEN    (IN/FF/FF): %d \n", spWert[13]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MALEN&ZEICHNEN      (KL/IN/FF): %d \n\n", spWert[14]);

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        WISSENSTALENTE\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "BRETT&GLÜCKSSPIEL   (KL/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[15]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "GEOGRAPHIE      (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[16]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "GESCHICHTSWISSEN    (KL/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[17]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "RELIGION        (KL/KL/CH): %d \n", spWert[18]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MECHANIK        (KL/KL/FF): %d \n", spWert[19]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "RECHNEN         (KL/KL/KL): %d \n", spWert[20]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SAGEN&LEGENDEN      (KL/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[21]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "RECHTSKUNDE     (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[22]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "STRATEGIE       (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[23]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MEDIZIN         (KL/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[24]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SEEFAHRT        (KL/IN/MU): %d \n\n", spWert[25]);

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        NATURTALENTE\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "FÄHRTENSUCHE        (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[26]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "FESSELN         (KL/FF/KK): %d \n", spWert[27]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "FISCHEN&ANGELN      (IN/FF/KO): %d \n", spWert[28]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ORIENTIRUNG     (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[29]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "PFLANZENKUNDE       (KL/IN/FF): %d \n", spWert[30]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "TIERKUNDE       (MU/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[31]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "WILDNISLEBEN        (IN/GE/KO): %d \n", spWert[32]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "JAGEN           (IN/KL/GE): %d \n", spWert[33]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "STERNKUNDE      (KL/KL/IN): %d \n\n", spWert[34]);

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        KÖRPERTALENTE\n\n");        

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KLETTERN        (MU/GE/KK): %d \n", spWert[35]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "BALANCIEREN     (GE/GE/KO): %d \n", spWert[36]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "REITEN          (IN/GE/KO): %d \n", spWert[37]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHWIMMEN       (GE/KO/KK): %d \n", spWert[38]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SELBSTBEHERRSCHUNG  (MU/IN/KO): %d \n", spWert[39]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SINGEN          (IN/CH/KL): %d \n", spWert[40]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SINNESSCHÄRFE       (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[41]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "TANZEN          (CH/GE/GE): %d \n", spWert[42]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "TASCHENDIEBSTAHL    (MU/IN/FF): %d \n", spWert[43]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "VERBERGEN       (MU/IN/GE): %d \n", spWert[44]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ZECHEN          (IN/KO/KK): %d \n", spWert[45]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHLEICHEN      (GE/GE/KO): %d \n", spWert[46]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MUSIKINSTRUMENTE    (KL/IN/KO): %d \n", spWert[47]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "REFLEXE         (GE/GE/FF): %d \n\n", spWert[48]);

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        GESELLSCHAFTSTALENTE\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "PREDIGEN        (MU/KL/IN): %d \n", spWert[49]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ÜBERZEUGEN      (MU/IN/CH): %d \n", spWert[50]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "BETÖREN         (MU/CH/CH): %d \n", spWert[51]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "EINSCHÜCHTERN       (MU/KK/KK): %d \n", spWert[52]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ETIKETTE        (KL/IN/CH): %d \n", spWert[53]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "GASSENWISSEN        (KL/IN/IN): %d \n", spWert[54]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MENSCHENKENNTNIS    (KL/IN/CH): %d \n", spWert[55]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ÜBERREDEN       (MU/KL/CH): %d \n", spWert[56]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "VERKLEIDEN      (IN/CH/GE): %d \n", spWert[57]);
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "WILLENSKRAFT        (MU/MU/IN): %d \n\n", spWert[58]);  

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "        KAMPFTECHNIKEN\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "ARMBRÜSTE       FF: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "BÖGEN           FF: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "MESSER          GE: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "HIEBWAFFEN      KK: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "KETTENWAFFEN        KK: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "RAUFEN          GE: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHILDE         KK: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHWERTER       KK: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "WURFWAFFEN      FF: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHUSSWAFFEN L      FF: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHUSSWAFFEN M      GE: \n");
    fprintf(CharakterFile, "SCHUSSWAFFEN S      KK: \n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "NAHKAMPFWAFFEN:\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "FERNKAMPFWAFFEN:\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    fprintf(CharakterFile, "INVENTAR:\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    fclose(CharakterFile);
}
else
{
    cout << "Error: Die Datei kann nicht geoeffnet werden.";        //Gibt eine Fehlermeldung aus, falls die Text datei nicht geöffnet werden kann
}
}
```

Comment: There is a **LOT** of extra code here. Remove it, and provide a [_Minimal_, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Emphasis Mine).

Comment: Please, please do not give variables Upper-Case names. Classes and Structs, it's okay to give Upper-Case Names. Variables with Upper-Case Names are very difficult to tell apart from Class names.

Comment: No dont' "_just put it there_". Remove unnecessary code

Comment: Stepping through with your debugger is the correct way to locate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct

```
grWert[3] = 70+(rand()%41);
```

your array is 3 is in size, but index is then 0-2, 3 will go past end of array.